# What Algorithm does Microsoft Office 2010 use for Encryption?

Tags: microsoft-office, encryption, cryptography

Does it use the standard AES 128bit key for encryption? I've searched a lot on Google, but I still haven't found the algorithm is uses for encrypting.

I'm encrypting a PowerPoint file.

Comment: I can never find where I saw it for reference, but it's based on the cryptographic providers you have installed on your system. Not sure how it chooses them, though

Answer (score 3):

Looking at this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179125.aspx

> When Office uses CryptoAPI, the
>   encryption algorithms depend on those
>   that are availablein a CSP (Crypto
>   Service Provider), which is part of
>   the Windows operating system. The
>   following registry key contains a list
>   of CSPs that are installed on a
>   computer:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Cryptography/Defaults/Provider
>
> The following CNG encryption
>   algorithms, or any other CNG cipher
>   extension installed on the system, can
>   be used with Office 2010 or the 2007
>   Office system SP2:
>
> AES, DES, DESX, 3DES, 3DES_112, and
>   RC2
>
> The following CNG hashing algorithms,
>   or any other CNG cipher extension that
>   is installed on the system, can be
>   used with Office 2010 or the 2007
>   Office system SP2:
>
> MD2, MD4, MD5, RIPEMD-128, RIPEMD-160,
>   SHA-1, SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512
>
> Although there are Office 2010
>   settings to change how encryption is
>   performed, when you encrypt Open XML
>   Format files (.docx, .xslx, .pptx, and
>   so on) the default values — AES
>   (Advanced Encryption Standard),
>   128-bit key length, SHA1, and CBC
>   (cipher block chaining) — provide
>   strong encryption and should be fine
>   for most organizations. AES encryption
>   is the strongest industry-standard
>   algorithm that is available and was
>   selected by the National Security
>   Agency (NSA) to be used as the
>   standard for the United States
>   Government. AES encryption is
>   supported on Windows XP SP2, Windows
>   Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2003,
>   and Windows Server 2008.

I would think maybe it uses AES 128 bit as the default.